# cuckoo sandbox integration in java

Tags: java, cuckoo

Please can anyone help for cuckoo sandbox integration for file and URL scan and than how to get the analysis report after the scan, i haven't got any idea for cuckoo sandbox integration in java even the official documentation and git repository used in python, if someone know any git repository or jar than please help me.

Cuckoo sandbox 2.0.6
https://cuckoo.sh/docs/usage/api.html#resources

https://docs.cuckoosandbox.org/en/latest/usage/dist/ - not working

Comment: First off, better (and working) Cuckoo docs are the ones at https://cuckoo.sh/docs/. 

For the rest, Cuckoo is built in Python/C so 'integration' could be tricky. From your question though, I get the feeling you just want to submit samples to a Cuckoo install for analysis? If so, you can use the REST API and just push requests to it using HTTP - https://cuckoo.sh/docs/usage/api.html